# If my site often says 'waiting for www.site.com' in the browser for quite a long time before actually opening, what does this mean?

Tags: php, apache-2.2

We've done a lot of performance optimisation on our site but it still seems slower than the majority of sites. The site in question is http://www.wikijob.co.uk. We run varnish, memcached etc etc.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,
Chris.

Comment: We need a *lot* more details than this. What kind of machine do you run, how much memory do you have, what optimization did you do, what OS you use etc.etc.etc. Tell us everything!

Comment: It means what it says and says what it means. The browser has contacted the server and is waiting for it to send a response. The question is whether the server is just "slow" because its overloaded or if there's a problem with code hanging. Having just visited the URL myself, it seemed a little slow but "ok", though you had quite a few different sites delivering elements of the page. That can certainly lead to a slowdown in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't seem to be on a server side. I checked load timings in Firebug, the page itself loaded quite fast. The problem is that you have lots of images on the page and a browser can't start rendering the page until it downloads them all for some reason. Something is definitely not optimal in HTML layout of the page. Probably you should add some kind of size hints.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Firefox, with firebug+yslow. Run a test with yslow and it shows 3 different area's that could be looked into:

Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN)
Add Expires headers
Configure entity tags (ETags)

I would also suggest that the number of individual images on the page slows loading quite a bit.